# Ionic 3 Directive Not Working

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I've been trying to create a directive in ionic and its just not working and i dont seem to know why.
I want the directive to allow  have the ability to auto resize itself. So when it has more text it just keeps resizing.

This is my code:
And my project is an ionic 3 project which is using angular 4, the new version.

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[auto-resize-text-input]' // Attribute selector
})
export class AutoResizeTextInput {
  constructor(public elem: ElementRef) {
    console.log('Hello AutoResizeTextInput Directive');
  }

  @HostListener('input', ['$event.target']) onInput() {
    this.resizeTextOnInput();
  }

  private resizeTextOnInput() {
    this.elem.nativeElement.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    this.elem.nativeElement.style.height = 'auto';
    this.elem.nativeElement.style.height = this.elem.nativeElement.scrollHeight + "px";
  }
}
```

Please help ????

Comment: hi, did you find a solution for that?

Comment: No still haven't found any solution, headed over to the ionic forum to ask and still no solution

Comment: Hopefully you can find answers here - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153499/ionic-3

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. The directive wasn't recognized by the app, but it didn't give any errors. So I removed it from main modules' `decalarations` and added to the page module' `decalarations`, which uses the directive and the problem is gone.

Comment: Works for me - moving directive declaration to the component's module.ts worked for me as well.

Comment: It doesn't work if the directive is added again to another module. It gives an error saying the directive is part of the declarations of 2 modules.

Answer (score 4):

If you were like me and needed this Directive across multiple components here's how I solved it.

Create a shared DirectiveModule named `directives.module.ts` in the same folder as your `app.module.ts` file and add your Directive you are trying to use under `declarations:[]` and `exports:[]`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SomeDirective } from './some.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [SomeDirective],
  exports: [SomeDirective]
})
export class DirectivesModule {}
```

Now import the shared directive module in the modules you need it:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SomePage } from './some';
import { DirectivesModule } from '../../app/directives.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DashboardPage
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(SomePage),
    DirectivesModule
  ]
})
export class SomePageModule {}
```

I couldn't find the answer I was looking for anywhere else, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

if you put your directive file in components folder. here is answer:

move your file from

`components/your-directive`

to

`directives/your-directive`

then rebuild it. Good luck!

Comment: It's actual in a directives folder, don't know what's wrong, the code looks pretty ok to me

Comment: as you known in ionic 3 any page you have a file page.module.ts . When you want to use any component, directive..you must import your directive here

Comment: @BitaHo answer should work. I removed the import from my app.module.ts and added it to the page.module.ts file and the directive started working.

Comment: @BitaHo Did you add it to the directive.module.ts as well?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help you:

If you are using directives in a component, import `directives.module.ts` into the `app.module.ts` and `components.module.ts` or simply import it in the `app.module.ts` to use your directive in a page.